# The proper name for a “story with photos”?

Tags: single-word-requests, journalism, photography

What is the proper English word that means a publication (e.g. in a paper or online) consisting of a series of photographs along with short author’s comments? Here is a [live example of such publication](https://www.tema.ru/eng/travel/ascension-island.2015/). Can it be called a *photo report* (and if yes, then *photo report* or *photoreport*?), or there is another established term for it?

Comment: I'm not sure we've got a settled word for this.  Different publications will brand these stories differently - the Washington Post calls them "visual stories".

Comment: I am informed that when such photo-heavy articles appeared in _Playboy_ magazine back in the 1960s and 1970s, they were termed **pictorials**.

Answer (score 3):

This is sometimes referred to as [**photojournalism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photojournalism) or a [**photo-essay**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo-essay).

The links above are to Wikipedia, but here are definitions from *Oxford English Dictionary*:

> **Photo-essay**: A series of thematically related photographs, usually supplemented or linked together by a narrative text or commentary; an essay, biography, etc., consisting of numerous photographs, with or without accompanying textual matter.

This definition is first cited in **1948**.

> The Atlantic Coast Exhibition by Eliot Elisofon, a Life Magazine **photo essay**, closes this week end.

- **1948**   Portland (Maine) *Press Herald* 5 Nov. 15/5

---

> **Photojournalism**: The use of photographs in journalism; journalism consisting primarily of photographs.

The first citation of this term is from **1938**:

> While **Photo-Journalism** is a comparatively new development in America, it has already taken quite an important position in Europe, where it developed during the past ten years.

- **1938**   A. Eisenstaedt in W. D. Morgan & H. M. Lester *Miniature Camera* Wk. iv. 67/1

Comment: Did I understand properly that _photojournalism_ is an occupation, and _photo-essay_ is a resulting product of this occupation?

Comment: @HydrochoerusHydrochaeris *photojournalism* can refer either to the act or the product.  You could say "There was some great photojournalism in that magazine."  You could also say "For a living I work in photojournalism."

Comment: Could I say “Today I came across three great photojournalisms”, or only “…three great photo-essays”?

Comment: The former would be unusual.  You might say "Today I came across three pieces of great photojournalism."

Answer (score 1):

Your link points to what is colloquially called a "photoblog" or a "photolog". It is rooted in the concatenation of "photo" and "blog". However, it is not recognized as an official word by OED or Webster (yet).

Photoblog : [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/photoblog)

> photoblog
>   NOUN
>
> A blog in which the postings are primarily in the form of photographs.
>
> ‘I'm helping them set up a photoblog which will hopefully give
>   everyone a chance to see some of those amazing pictures’

Wikipedia has an [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoblog).

Comment: How would you call this kind of story, if its contents and composition were similar to my link, but published not on the Internet, but, say, in a paper magazine in 1970s?

Answer (score 0):

**photo story**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/142770?redirectedFrom=photo%20spread#eid30392630)

> n. a story with accompanying photographs; (in early use also
>   occasionally) a story told in photographic form, a film.

As in:

> 1992    Working on her photography in the late '40s, she succeeded in
>   getting a major **photostory** published in the London-based ‘Picture
>   Post’.